# How do I launch a standalone SWF from within an Adobe AIR application?

Tags: air, flash

I'm completely new to AIR but what I'm trying to do feels like it should be quite easy.

I want my AIR app to execute (launch) an SWF in the standalone Flash Player (just like if I were to double click it).

Please note that I don't want the AIR app to embed the SWF. Just run it.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AIR-Runtime is (still) not able to launch external Applications, except Acrobat Reader for PDFs and the default Browser (you can let the browser display the swf).

I think you need some of this Frameworks:

- [FluorineFx Aperture](http://aperture.fluorinefx.com/)
- [Merapi](http://www.merapiproject.net/)

What's the sense behind your plan, why AIR?

Answer (score 1):

Using Adobe AIR, you could launch / load the SWF into a separate native window. It would run in the same process as the AIR app loading / launching it, but the experience would be the similar if not the same for the end user.

mike chambers

mesh@adobe.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the this, running it through a browser might be my solution then. FYI I'm using AIR to write some settings to a local text file that the SWF then can read.

Answer (score 0):

Most people don't have the standalone player - only people with Flash installed, so this isn't a very good idea, I don't think. Could you open a new AIR window with just the swf in it?